# Regex remove text not followed by other text

Tags: regex

I need to be able to get rid of all of these:

```
  name:
    group:
    - Rank
```

but **not** these:

```
  name:
    group:
    - Rank
    - Donor
```

using Notepad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\b(?:name:\s+group:\s+-\s+Rank)(?!\s*-)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/19

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative lookahead based regex like below.

```
.*name:\s+group:\s+- *Rank.*(?!\n *\S)
```

Then replace the matched chars with an empty string.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jD9fH2/3)

Comment: http://gyazo.com/df3a28968c574e8bba2c4e0889679aa4 It appears to work on regex101.com, but in Notepad++ stuff that **shouldn't** be selected is being selected

Comment: provide a pastebin link, because the above link take more time to load. Or edit your question.